# Prevent "Update-database" using ef core code first migration

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Is there a way to prevent a user from calling "Update-Database" (Visual Studio) or "dotnet ef database update" (CLI) when using code first migrations?  We want to force users to generate scripts when updating a database and prevent them from accidently updating a production database with ef core tools.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework simply generates a script and then it executes in the database. So in this case if you want to restrict somebody from updating a database, you just need to add some restrictions in your Database. For example you can create users and give them Read only permission.

Comment: This would not work.  We use windows authentication for our db access. VS sends windows credentials to access the db for update.  We still want to allow users to modify the db, just not through visual studio.  Microsoft recommends always updating production db using script and not ef tools